# Building vdproj from commandline cause visual studio (devenv) to crash

Tags: c#, visual-studio, command-line, msbuild, devenv

I use devenv.com to build a sln contain many projects(c# .net and few c++ dlls).

Near the end of the build, when it is time to build the vdproj for msi generation, devenv crashes and build is left incomplete.
The build went through only once somehow, but the MSI file that was generated did not have  correct settings(it was supposed to remove the previous version and install a newer one, but it immediately exited by popping a error dialog indicating a previous installation)

I would like to know what is wrong and how to build a sln containing many projects(including couple of vdproj) using devenv on the commandline.

Regards,
Vicky

Comment: This is severely under-documented.  Post this to connect.microsoft.com, they'll need to know the VS version and your .sln and project files to troubleshoot it.

Comment: Please provide more details about error